# Why do the inductance calculated from the simple solenoid formula and the Lorenz formula give such different results?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

I am trying to understand the different formulae out there for calculating the self-inductance of a solenoid given its geometry, and am trying to resolve a discrepancy.

The simplest case is that of a "long" solenoid with length $l$, assumed to be much longer than the radius $r$, and consisting of $N$ turns. The expression for this scenario in SI units [metres, Henry] is simply

\begin{equation}
L = \frac{\mu_0 N^2A}{l} = \frac{\mu_0 N^2\pi r^2}{l}
\end{equation}

The above expression suffers from the fact that there will be corrections arising in practice from the two ends of the solenoid, which is not infinitely long.

However, as I understand it, there is a more accurate expression derived by Lorenz, given by Eq. (72) on p. 118 of the following reference: [Formulas and Tables for the Calculation of Mutual and Self Inductance](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/bulletin/08/nbsbulletinv8n1p1_A2b.pdf), by Rosa & Grover. The equation reads:

\begin{equation}
L = \frac{32}{3}\frac{\pi N^2 r^3}{l^2}\left\{\frac{2k^2-1}{k^3}E(k)\;+\;\frac{1-k^2}{k^3}F(k)\;-1\; \right\}
\end{equation}

where 
\begin{equation}
k^2 = \frac{4r^2}{4r^2+l^2}
\end{equation}

and $F(k)$ and $E(k)$ are the complete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind, respectively. Note that this expression I think is in cgs units [cm, Abhenry = $10^{-9}$H].

Now, I believe the Lorenz formula is valid regardless of the length of the solenoid (although it still assumes the solenoid is made from an infinitely thin current sheet). Therefore, I would have expected that for large values of solenoid length $l$ the two should give similar results?

To test this, I plug in values of a solenoid with $l=1\text{m}$, $r=1\text{cm}$, and $N=1000$. This satisfies the condition $l\gg r$ and so the two should give similar results.

Using the basic formula, the inductance is
\begin{equation}
L = \frac{4\pi\times 10^{-7}\times 1000^2\times \pi \times (10^{-2})^2}{1} = 3.9\times 10^{-4}\; \text{H} = 390\;\mu\text{H}
\end{equation}

To calculate the inductance using the Lorenz formula, I use the following Matlab function, to take advantage of their built-in elliptical integrals:

```
# Calculate inductance of a solenoid using Lorenz's formula

r = 1 [cm];
l = 100 [cm];
N = 1000 [turns];

k = 2*r/sqrt(4*r^2 + l.^2);
[F, E] = ellipke(k);

L = (32/3)*(pi*N^2*r^3)/(l^2)*( (2*k^2-1)*E/k^3 + (1-k^2)*F/k^3 - 1);
```

The result of this is $6.9\times10^6$ abhenry $= 6.9$ mH. This is obviously very different to the $390\;\mu\text{H}$ obtained with the simple formula. I have checked and checked, but cannot find the mistake - can anyone tell me what is going on here? Did I make a mistake in the calculation, or is there some physical reason why they should be so far different? I would expect a small error, but not as big as the factor of ~20 observed.

Comment: use $k^2$ in ellipke(k^2) and you get the right number.

Comment: @hyportnex Excellent - great spot! Why should I use $k^2$ though? The reference document clearly says "F and E are complete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind of modulus $k$"...

Comment: it is a matter of definition, habits, customs, conventions, etc., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral The elliptic functions and elliptic integrals are notorious for their historically inconsistent and counter intuitive conventions. You should always check how it is defined. Obviously, I am speaking from unpleasant experience...

Comment: Okay I understand. The "modulus" is $k=\sqrt{m}$, where $m$ is the so-called "parameter"... it seems like the Matlab function takes as its input the parameter...  didn't realise this subtlety with the definitions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @hyportnex, I made a mistake on the input to the Matlab *ellipke()* function, and there is a difference between the "parameter" of an elliptic integral and the "modulus". As suggested, making the input *ellipke($k^2$)* instead of *ellipke($k$)* fixed the problem. I am writing out a formal answer, so it can be accepted.

Comment: from matlab help "ellipke Complete elliptic integral.
    [K,E] = ellipke(M) returns the value of the complete elliptic
    integrals of the first and second kinds, evaluated for each
    element of M.  As currently implemented, M is limited to 0 <= M <= 1.  
    [K,E] = ellipke(M,TOL) computes the complete elliptic integrals to
    the accuracy TOL instead of the default TOL = EPS(CLASS(M)).
     Some definitions of the complete elliptic integrals use the modulus
    k instead of the parameter M.  They are related by M = k^2."

Comment: Sorry, if you write it as an answer I can accept it for you.